# Displaying dynamic created jpg inside an html apache

Tags: apache2, cgi

I have an image created by a CGI script.. if you call the script directly it displays quite happily with.

```
Content-type: image/jpeg
```

However I need to embed this inside a page, and no matter what I try the browsers just display raw data. I've tried octet-stream, binary and a few other things to no avail.

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Content-type: image/jpeg"
echo ""
/usr/bin/xearth -pos fixed/10/144.96 -shade -size 320/320 -gif |convert gif: jpeg:-
```

.

```
<!--#include file="head.shtml" -->
<!--#exec cgi="/cgi-bin/xearth.cgi" -->
<!--#include file="tail.shtml" -->
```

A

Comment: could you please show some code of cgi and html, this could help to help

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm sure I tried it this way before I posted.  However it came back as a way to do it from another source.  SO I must've screwed it up before somehow, because that sure as heck works now.